# How to resolve the ImportError: cannot import name 'DesicionTreeClassifier' from 'sklearn.tree' in python?

Tags: python

*Hello there,
I am new to python and I was trying out a project on jupyter notebook when I encountered an error which I couldn't resolve. I'd really appreciate some help.
This is my code:*

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DesicionTreeClassifier 
music_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\python\python382\music.csv')    
X=music_data.drop(columns=['genre']) 
y=music_data['genre']    
model=DesicionTreeClassifier() 
model.fit(X,y)  
music_data
```

*And i got the output as :*

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2540/2462038274.py in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 from sklearn.tree import DesicionTreeClassifier #using desicion tree algo here to make model[we import DesicionTree module from tree module which is imported from sklearn library]
      3 music_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\python\python382\music.csv')
      4 
      5   ##Cleaning and segregating data

ImportError: cannot import name 'DesicionTreeClassifier' from 'sklearn.tree' (C:\python\python382\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\__init__.py)
```

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 1):

You have missspelled the fumction name `DesicionTreeClassifier`  is in reality `DecisionTreeClassifier`